# Checking whether box and gift colors satisfy the given criteria

Tags: python

I have this piece of code where it based on this condition:

1. Box Color can only be in red, white and black
2. If the box's type is A then any color is allowed
3. Box's type C is not allowed at all
4. For the gift, only green and blue color is allowed and the size cannot be small
5. Box and gift color cannot be same

views.py

```
    boxColor = ["red", "white", "black"]
    giftColor = ["green", "blue"]
    if box.color != gift.color:
        if gift.color in giftColor and gift.size != "small":
            if (box.type == "A") or (box.type != "C" and box.color in boxColor):
                return True
            else:
                return False
        else:
            return False
    else:
        return False
```

Is there is a way to simplify my code that I can make this more efficient ?

Comment: Welcome to Code Review@SE. A `return` statement looks lacking context without a `def`, and the title doesn't follow site conventions: Please (re)visit [How do I ask a Good Question?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this should be simplified. Prefer sets since you're doing membership checks, and write this as a boolean expression rather than a series of `if` checks with `return`s:

```
return (
    box.type != 'C'
    and (
        box.type == 'A'
        or box.color in {'red', 'white', 'black'}
    )
    and box.color != gift.color
    and gift.size != 'small'
    and gift.color in {'green', 'blue'}
)
```